# How to execute other commands during input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is my code `data = input('--').encode()` and I want to run `print(s.recv(1024).decode())` whilst the input is being filled in and whilst things in my program are happening as I need that code to be ran every 0.1 seconds or so.

Comment: Try threading:  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html

Comment: You really want output printing while the user is trying to input something? I seriously doubt it...

Comment: Have a look at `man select`

Answer (score 0):

There is only one general way to do what you are trying to do, and it is quite complicated.

The input() function pauses the program, so the only way to do something else at the same time it to make the computer run two things at the same time.  Threading is an advanced concept and can cause many issues in your programs if not done correctly, but it is a VERY useful thing to know how to do, especially in Python, since it can dramatically increase the speed of the programs you are running, and Python is one of the slower languages, one of the many prices of easy-to-use languages.

I suggest you learn all of Python's basics, gain a year or two of experience, and then learn about threading.  Refer to the following website to learn how to use threads:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html